# Pull most updated version of database in view

Tags: ios, database, fmdb

I am trying to make a table of favorites based on a FMDB database.  Pressing the button on another screen registers a change in the database but the app has to be reloaded in order for the favorites page to update the most current add.  Is there a better place to do this so that the favorites page will reflect db changes automatically?  Below is the code I'm using to call the DB in the favorites view controller.

```
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); // Get the documents directory

docsDir = dirPaths[0];

NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"passages.db"]];

FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
[database open];

FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM passages WHERE favorite=1"];
NSMutableArray *favorites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
while ([results next]){
    NSMutableDictionary *pass = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [pass setObject:[results stringForColumn: @"thing1"] forKey:@"thing1"];
    [pass setObject:[results stringForColumn: @"thing2"] forKey:@"thing2"];
    [pass setObject:[results stringForColumn: @"thing3"] forKey:@"thing3"];

    [favorites addObject:pass];
}
[results close];
[database close];
```

Comment: I guess you need to reload the data on the favorites page? If you execute the code above **after** you add a favorite what happens?

Comment: if you are using some table to display your favorites, you need to reload it using something like [self.table reloadData] optimally in -viewWillAppear method of your favorite view controller.

Comment: @Astri the favorite is added on the first page you see and the favorites page is navigated to afterwards

Comment: As Ayan suggested, you should re-query your database to get the fresh data, then populate it on viewWillAppear